# Python - Sorting Nested Dictionary using length of nested values

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting, dictionary

I've a nested dictionary DictA as below

```
Dict A  
{
'a': {'k1': 'v1', 'k2': 'v2', 'k3': 'v3', 'k4': 'v4,v5'}, 
'b': {'k1': 'v1', 'k2': 'v2', 'k3': 'v3', 'k4': 'v4'}
}
```

Nested Dictionaries 'a' and 'b' are almost same except the value of 'k4'. 
How do I sort DictA based on the above difference in value's length.

I want the Dict A to be sorted as below,

```
Dict A = 
{
'b': {'k1': 'v1', 'k2': 'v2', 'k3': 'v3', 'k4': 'v4'},
'a': {'k1': 'v1', 'k2': 'v2', 'k3': 'v3', 'k4': 'v4,v5'}
}
```

Please advise.

Comment: Not again... apologies, but you can't sort dictionaries. With python3.6, you can create new dictionaries with sorted order, but you still can't sort them.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I sort a dictionary by value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613183/how-do-i-sort-a-dictionary-by-value)

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to copy the dictionary to a new temp one to do operations

Answer (score -1):

Use `key` with your call to sort. In this argument, pass in a lambda to `key` to sort by a specific value. So:

```
sorted_dict = sorted (DictA, key = lambda inner_dict: len (inner_dict ["k4"]))
```

Comment: Thanks. But I've a huge nested dictionary, I'm struggling with the syntax of iterating through nested dictionaries values by length to sort it.

Comment: What version of Python are you using that has `dict`s with a `sort` method?

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more? Is the dictionary always the same deep? Etc.

Comment: SORRY meant `sorted()`, I'll fix it now, care to re-upvote?

Comment: Python version 3.6

Comment: No, he was talking to me, I incorrectly called `.sort()` instead of `sorted()` and he was reminding me of that.

Comment: The length of nested dictionary varies....For eg: Dict A has 4 nested dictionaries with varied number of nested values. and Dict B might have 2 nested dictionaries with varied number of nested values.

Comment: Ok, and where is the one with `"k4"`, or the equivalent of it

Comment: I didn't get your question. If you see my question DictA has two nested dicts 'a' and 'b' and the only difference between them is the length of values. I need to identify the nested dict which has minimum value length.

Comment: Yes but you said there could be multiple **layers** of dicts inside your main one. I need to know if the value you want to check will always be inside a certain layer or if it will move around.

Comment: It will move around definitely.

Comment: OK...are there any other keys like it (even in the other layers)? I want to know if I can search for the key in all the layers of the main dict. If not, please post all (or at least most) of your code so I can look for alternative methods

Comment: Or if you could describe to me a "pattern" or "rule" that dictates where the value we're looking for will be.

Comment: I'm not looking for any pattern. All I'm looking for is the length of the values of a nested key. Dict A  
{
'a': {'k1': 'v1', 'k2': 'v2', 'k3': '1,2,3,4', 'k4': '1,2,3'}, 
'b': {'k1': 'v1', 'k2': 'v2', 'k3': '1', 'k4': '1,2,3'},
'c': {'k1': 'v1', 'k2': 'v2', 'k3': '1,2', 'k4': '1,2,3'}
}

Comment: From the above Dict A, I want to insert into another dictionary say Dict B with sorted order b,c,a instead of a,b,c in DictA

Comment: Yah so my answer still works. Unless of course, there will be dictionaries inside -- for example -- `a`. Then we need to get a little more complicated. And I edited my answer to give the **length** of the `"k4"` value, not just the value itself.

Comment: In any case, can you just post your code as an edit to your answer? It will give me all the context I need. Edit: In response to your edit above, dictionaries CANNOT be sorted. I **can** make you a list of key, value pairs, if you'd like...

Comment: I won't be able to specify K4 directly, it could be any value. I need to iterate the dictionary items (all values -maybe using some loop function to know the length and then sort.

Comment: OK, just post the rest of your code pls and Ill see what I can do

Comment: Thanks for your help!. But, the code is all messed up and I'm just trying to rewrite from scratch. As specified in the question, I'm trying to iterate each dictionary which has multiple nested dictionaries and try to sort them and insert into a new dictionary (using ordered) so that it remains in the same order.

Comment: Again, dictionaries have no order. It may look like they do, but they really don't and can shuffle anytime. So please, don't ask for a sorted dictionary. Like I said, I can make you a list of lists (key value pairs).